# How to accept or replace Ampersand in Netsuite

Tags: pdf, netsuite

I have this problem with netsuite PDF Template, I need to replace or accept this type of caracter (&) in a field.

I use replace like this:
[${record.entity.altname?upper_case?replace("&","&")}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vi2k.png)

but my result is
RIVIERA WINES & SPIRITS SAPI DE CV [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtZw6.png)

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What do you want the output to be? What is the input you are transforming? What you wrote shows up and replacing ampersand with ampersand.  Are you trying to replace the ampersand with `&amp;`

Comment: Hello! The string is RIVIERA WINES & SPIRITS SAPI DE CV but in PDF netsuite don't show the &, i need to show them

Comment: I have searched and some people use replace but my result is RIVIERA WINES &AMP; SPIRITS SAPI DE CV

Answer (score 0):

I took a look and I think what I've used for this is the `?html` built-in. So:

```
${record.entity.altname?upper_case?html}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer bknight. I use the ?html but in the PDF still appears  RIVIERA WINES &AMP; SPIRITS SAPI DE CV :/

Comment: what is the context  of the template? Are you in `<pdf></pdf>` tags?  I am generating transaction pdfs where a customer who has an ampersand in their name displays as expected with no extra handling. e.g., like `<span style="font-size: 12pt;">${record.entity.altname}</span>`